# How do I parse a file name format like 'PUBLIC001' with a Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex

Need help with a regular expression that parses a file name

File will be named PUBLIC001
'PUBLIC' is static text in all file names
Last 3 digits- day of the year.001(Jan 1)-366(Dec31st on a leap year) is valid range

What would be regular expression. Is there a way to limit the max to 366?

THanks

Comment: Using `Path` you could do `int dayOfYear = Integer.parseInt(p.getFileName().toString().replaceAll("PUBLIC(\\d{3}).*", "$1"));` For current year: `LocalDate fileWhen = Year.now().atDay(dayOfYear);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pattern like:

```
 PUBLIC([0-2]\d\d|3[0-5]\d|36[0-6])
```

would do it.

Or if validating the date number doesn't matter, then something like:

```
PUBLIC\d\d\d
```

or

```
PUBLIC\d{3}
```

would do it too.

Add a `^` and `$` to the beginning and end, respectively, if the file should not have any other parts to it (e.g., this will avoid matching `NOT-PUBLIC001`, or PUBLIC001002)

like:

```
^PUBLIC\d{3}$
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use the simple 3-digit regular expression rather than trying to constrain what digits can be used, and then (if needed) follow it up with a separate semantic check on the value of the 3 digits. This gives an opportunity for a better error diagnostic.  Not to mention deciding whether the limit is 365 or 366 :-)